# Setup version number in xcode for project beta testing

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app. I have given the option for beta testing to my clients. Currently my beta testing build which I uploaded to itunesconnect is 1.1(build 3). I think this time, client will clear the bugs and I will get to submit for App store.

My issue is as its in version 1.1. Can I upload another build as 1.0 and submit for Appstore? means there should be two version 1.0 for appstore and 1.1 for beta testing version. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried? This is easily testable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. but one version upload then second is not equal or less then first version. you can upload 1.0 for testing and 1.1 for app store.

Comment: Thats completely contradicting... can i upload 1.0 for appstore when there is 1.1 for testing???

Comment: you can upload any app but you need to upload first 1.0 and then 1.1.

Comment: @ Keyur... you are not understanding my point..... My client is checking version 1.1 through testflight.... when app clears testing phase.. I want to upload 1.0 version of app to appstore final review is it possible or not????

Comment: you can't upload 1.1 then 1.0. Apple follow ascending order.

Comment: I just upload now 1.0(build 3) and I can select that for appstore review in itunesconnect(prepare for submission) where my client is checking 1.1 through testflight...how is this possible?

Comment: Its possible I think. As I have not submit for appstore review(prepare for submission) so, I could upload 1.0 , it does not matter what version I am using for testflight....Please check docs...

Comment: @Rajesh...I have changed the version number not build number. You are not following the question I suppose... You are talking about the build version...which should be higher when uploading a build

Comment: Sorry @Saty that is possible. I understand your actual problem.

Comment: Hear you upload two version 1.0 fro live and 1.1 for testfight right? then no any issue...

Comment: Thanks man...Thats the thing I was searching for...Thanks a TON

Comment: One more thing... I have given version 1.1(build 2) for testing and now I am giving 1.0(build 4)..will there be any issue while installing in client end. (Purely for Testflight)

Comment: for testflight only one version latest version install. lower any version not install.